# Using XPATH to select specific values from an XML document?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to select specific values from a xml document using XPath. The xml is stored into a string varibale "tmp". This xml is the result of a query performed on a external API.

sample XML contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Results>
<Checks>
<Check id="wbc">
<Linespeed>6000 </Linespeed>
<Provider>BT WBC </Provider>
</Check>
<Check id="adsl">
<Linespeed>2048 </Linespeed>
<Provider>BT ADSL </Provider>
</Check>
</Checks>
</Results>
```

Using XPATH in code behind I want to be able to select the `<Linespeed>` and `<Provider>` only for `id=adsl`, then store the value in a string variable for later use. I want to achieve this withouth the use of a separate xslt stylesheet. Any assistance on this will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Thanks to everyone for the assistance, using the xpath expression I now want to actually put it to use as follows:

```
//Creating an XPATH epression
String strExpression1;
strExpression1 = "Results/Checks/Check[@id = 'adsl']/Linespeed";


//Loading the xml document
XmlDocument doc;
doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(tmp);

//Create an XmlNamespaceManager to resolve the default namespace.
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("bk", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt");

//Selecting Linespeed from Check id='adsl'
XmlNode Check;
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
Check = root.SelectSingleNode(strExpression1, nsmgr);


//Assigning the the results of the XPATH expression to the string variable Linespeedval
string Linespeedval = Check.ToString();

//Adding a control to display the xpath results of the xml query
AvailabilityCheckerResults2.Controls.Add(new 
LiteralControl(Linespeedval));
```

In theory I should be able to see the value of  being displayed on a page inside of PlaceHolder named "AvailabilityCheckerResults2", but I get a error instead. Is there a way to assign the results from the xpath expression to a string variable? Thanks again

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xpath expression to select `<Linespeed/>` and `<Provider/>` for `<Check id="adsl"/>`

is : `//Linespeed[ancestor::Check[@id = 'adsl']]`  <-- This selects all Linespeed nodes whose ancestor is a check element with id = adsl

Alternatively you could use something like :

```
/Results/Checks/Check[@id = 'adsl']/Linespeed
```

This selects the line speed which is a child of a Check with @id = 'adsl' as it stands in your document.

For the Provider you can use the same methodology.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as a starting point.

```
var elements = XElement.Parse(tmp).Elements("Checks").Elements("Check").Where (xe => xe.Attribute("id").Value=="adsl");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `/Results/Checks/Check[@id='adsl']/Linespeed` or  `/Results/Checks/Check[@id='adsl']/Provider` (what do you want to select, you missed it?)

Comment: Thanks, I have added extra code to include this xpath expression, but I get an error instead of the desired output. Is there a better simpler way to go about this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to select the `<Linespeed>` and `<Provider>` only for
>   id=adsl

**Use**:

```
/*/*/Check[@id = 'adsl']/*[self::Linespeed or self::Provider]
```

This selects any `Linespeed` or `Provider` element that is a child of a `Check` the string value of whose `id` attribute is `"adsl"` and that is a grand-child of the top element of the XML document.

**If it is guaranteed that a `Check` can only have `Linespeed` or `Provider` children, then the above can be simplified to**:

```
/*/*/Check[@id = 'adsl']/*
```

This selects any element that is a child of a `Check` the string value of whose `id` attribute is `"adsl"` and that is a grand-child of the top element of the XML document.

If you want to only select the `Linespeed` element, use:

```
/*/*/Check[@id = 'adsl']/Linespeed
```

If you want to only select the `Provider` element, use:

```
/*/*/Check[@id = 'adsl']/Provider
```